# Copy file over TCP socket in Ruby slow

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm in need to transfer a file via sockets:

```
# sender
require 'socket'
SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 10

TCPSocket.open('127.0.0.1', 12345) do |socket| 
  File.open('c:/input.pdf', 'rb') do |file|
      while chunk = file.read(SIZE)
      socket.write(chunk)
    end
  end
end  


# receiver
require 'socket'
require 'benchmark'
SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 10

server =  TCPServer.new("127.0.0.1", 12345)
puts "Server listening..."            
client = server.accept       

time = Benchmark.realtime do
  File.open('c:/output.pdf', 'w') do |file|
    while chunk = client.read(SIZE)
      file.write(chunk)
    end
  end
end

file_size = File.size('c:/output.pdf') / 1024 / 1024
puts "Time elapsed: #{time}. Transferred #{file_size} MB. Transfer per second: #{file_size / time} MB" and exit
```

Using Ruby 1.9 i get a transfer rate of ~ 16MB/s (~ 22MB/s using 1.8) when transfering a 80MB PDF file from / to localhost. I'm new to socket programming, but that seems pretty slow compared to just using FileUtils.cp.  Is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Comment: This has probably no influence on the speed, but your File.open('c:/output.pdf', 'w') do |file| 
line would better be File.open('c:/output.pdf', 'wb') do |file|
to correspond with your binary read, otherwise your binary transfered files come out truncated

Answer (score 1):

Well, even with `localhost`, you still have to go through *some* of the TCP stack, introducing inevitable delays with packet fragmentation and rebuilding. It probably doesn't go out on the wire where you'd be limited to 100 megaBITs (~12.5 MB/s) per second or a gigibit (~125 MB/s) theoretical maximum.

None of that overhead exists for raw file copying disk to disk. You should keep in mind that even SATA1 gave you 1.5 gigabits/sec and I'd be surprised if you were still running on that backlevel. On top of that, your OS itself will undoubtedly be caching a lot of stuff, not possible when sending over the TCP stack.

16MB per second doesn't sound too bad to me.

Comment: Well, of course there is _some_ overhead. I just tried to transfer the same file using net/ftp and i get transfer rates of 85 MB/s (same machine, same harddisk), so i'm still wondering why using the socket is about 5 times slower...

Comment: Well, it may be that Ruby itself adds overhead although I would expect the read/write calls to be straight C so shouldn't be _too_ bad.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but why can't you compress before you send, then decompress on the receiving end?

```
require 'zlib'

def compress(input)
  Zlib::Deflate.deflate(input)
end

def decompress(input)
  Zlib::Inflate.inflate(input)
end
```

(Shameless plug) AFT (https://github.com/wlib/aft) already does what you're making